# Docker compose problems (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose for the backend (.net Core) and for the Angular frontend. These should communicate with each other. For this I tried a network. But I always get the following message:

**[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /appinfo from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)**

Both containers are running. The backend-compose is started via Visual Studio. The frontend-compose is started using the powershell.

I have tried both port 80 and 5000 in the frontend.  The result is the same.

For the network I tried it without external. For the external I created the network manually with "docker network create test_network".

backend docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend_sql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-GA-ubuntu
    container_name: testsql
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "1440:1433"
    volumes:
     - testsqldata:/var/opt/mssql

  backend_api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}backendapi
    container_name: testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backendAPI/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - test_network
    depends_on:
     - backend_sql
    ports:
     - "5000:80"

networks:
  test_network:
    external:
        name: test_network

volumes:
  testsqldata:
    driver: local
    name: testsqldata
```

frontend docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  testapp:
    container_name: testapp
    build: .
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
    volumes:
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - ".:/app"

networks:
  test_network:
    external:
      name: test_network
```

frontend dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200 49153
CMD npm run start
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --poll 500 --disableHostCheck",
    "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.server.config.js",
```

proxy.server.config.js:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            '/api',
        ],
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        ws: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: you should use the service names to connect between the containers not "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

From [the Docker Compose networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/),

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.

You should use the container names as hostname.